# Why RAM is less than L2 cache on AM335x?

Tags: memory, cache

On the AM335x device, the L2 cache size is 256KB, but the RAM size is 64K. i.e. the size of RAM is actually less than the L2 cache. I want to understand why it is so. Maybe only the designers at TI can respond exactly, which I have also done (i.e. posted this question in a TI-forum), but if it is general computer science, or HW topic - than can you please give your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AM335x devices are usually used with external RAM. The internal RAM is used for bootstrapping. It can of course be used as the only RAM, but the more common case is to connect external DRAM of sizes up to gigabytes.